# Why does Microsoft Authenticator show email domain when using email as label rather than the Issuer?

Tags: google-authenticator, authenticator

I am using TwoFactorAuth.net to show a QR code for scanning into an authenticator app.  This works if I use a name in the "label" parameter.  However, if I use an email address as the "label" in creating the QR code, Microsoft Authenticator uses the domain from the email as the Issuer, rather than the provided issuer.

To wit:
EX 1 - Not Email (i.e. sample code):

- private readonly TwoFactorAuth tfa = new TwoFactorAuth("MyCompany",
  qrcodeprovider: new QRCoder.QRCoderQRCodeProvider());
- Model.GetQrCodeImageAsDataUri("Bob Ross", (string)Session["secret"])"

RESULT:
[image: NameLabel]

EX 2 - Email Label:

- private readonly TwoFactorAuth tfa = new TwoFactorAuth("MyCompany", qrcodeprovider: new QRCoder.QRCoderQRCodeProvider());
- img src="@Model.GetQrCodeImageAsDataUri("mypaint@thebobross.com", (string)Session["secret"])"

RESULT:
[image: EmailLabel]

However, the email DOES work properly in Google Authenticator:
[image: GoogleAuthenticator]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the standard [Key Uri Format](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator/wiki/Key-Uri-Format#introduction):

```
otpauth://TYPE/LABEL?PARAMETERS
```

I couldn't find any substantial information on how Microsoft Authenticator parses *otpauth* URI but after testing different ways I have come to the conclusion that **if an email address alone is given as a LABEL, Microsoft Authenticator picks the subdomain of whatever TLD is present**. Actually, [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name#Domain_name_syntax) also says different parts of a domain name are called *labels* so probably that's the logic there.

Anyway, I solved it by adding **Issuer** before the **email address** as LABEL (mind the ':' separator).

```
"MyCompany:mypaint@thebobross.com"
```

I've successfully tested this with Microsoft and Google Authenticator. Both show *MyCompany* as LABEL.

Comment: Thanks @manavchopra! Adding Issuer as Label before the email address solved my issue as well, believe the answer should be marked as accepted.